# how to groupBy muitiple columns in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have the array input below and need to group by multiple keys.

```json
[
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A001"
  },
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A001"
  },
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A002"
  },
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S002",
    "item": "A001"
  }, 
  {
    "storeCode": 1202,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A002"
  }
]
```

How do I get this to group by both `storeCode` and `soNo`.

```json
[
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A001"
  },
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A002"
  },
  {
    "storeCode": 1201,
    "soNo": "S002",
    "item": "A001"
  }, 
  {
    "storeCode": 1202,
    "soNo": "S001",
    "item": "A002"
  }
]
```

Comment: You say sort in the question but it means group, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to sort the data, and not group it. You can do that like this quickly:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload orderBy $.soNo) orderBy $.storeCode
```

If you're looking to get only distinct objects, DO NOT use concatenation - this technically isn't correct as overlap happens. Do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload distinctBy $
```

Comment: @maomifadacai I've updated my answer to reflect what I think you want. You can also build a custom object, so `distinctBy ({storeCode: $.storeCode, soNo: $.soNo})` would only distinct by those fields, though I suspect you wanted all fields.